# Careers 2.0 profile shows incomplete status if a user is not looking for additional employment

Tags: support, jobs, profile-page

I'm currently employed full time as a manager and am thinking about placing some job ads on the Careers 2.0 website.  However, it seems as if the website wants to list my profile as "incomplete" if I do not check one of the boxes indicating that I am looking for work.

Is this intended, or a bug?

Comment: "placing some job ads"—What exactly do you mean by this phrase? Are you looking for someone to hire?

Comment: Yes, we have positions open.  However, I should have left that out as it doesn't relate to my bug.  The issue is that the website is telling me that my profile is incomplete because I'm missing "objectives".  But the only objectives that move me towards a complete profile, are ones that would have me listed as looking for employment.  Since I'm not looking for employment, I would think this should be an optional item, not required for the purpose of having a "complete" profile.

Comment: Just for clarity, the reason I had mentioned that I was thinking of placing some job ads is due to my desire to show that not everyone on the Careers site will be looking for employment - some will actually be looking to hire.  Hence, I didn't think that the objectives should be a requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Careers.SO has two faces—candidates and employers. It seems like you were trying to create a candidate profile, even though you were looking for someone to hire. For this reason, your profile is *"incomplete"*—it's Careers' job to find you a job. If you just want to use it as a CV but you're perfectly happy and aren't interested in getting a new job, that's fine—but your profile isn't complete because it hasn't met its purpose.

If you want to hire people, however, you need to either [post a job or search candidates from the employer side](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer). This works differently—you don't create a "[personal profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv)", but this is the right way to look for people to hire. If you select "post a job", you will have places to fill in a form that's sort of a company/job profile.

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  You're correct, I didn't realize that when I was setting up an account.  I'll leave it there, in it's incomplete state - in case I do need it at some point.